# getKeysByPrefix does not return defaults, only remote values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

Firebase remote config has a method to return a set of keys. But it only returns keys that exists on the server-side. 
(The keys i've defined in remoteconfig_defaults.xml do not.)

Used code:

```
FirebaseRemoteConfig instance = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
instance.setDefaults(R.xml.remoteconfig_defaults);
Set<String> keysSet = instance.getKeysByPrefix("");
```

And xml:

```
<defaultsMap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<entry>
    <key>loading_phrase</key>
    <value>Fetching config…</value>
</entry>
...
</defaultsMap>
```

Any ideas on how to get the keys of the defaults as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the the defaults are in XML, an XML-parser can be used to get the keys.

```
public static Set<String> getDefaultKeys(Context context, @XmlRes int xmlRes) {
    Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();
    XmlResourceParser xmlResourceParser = context.getResources().getXml(xmlRes);
    try {
        boolean isInKeyTag = false;
        while (xmlResourceParser.getEventType() != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (xmlResourceParser.getEventType() == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) {
                String tagName = xmlResourceParser.getName();
                if (tagName.equals("key")) {
                    isInKeyTag = true;
                }
            }
            if (xmlResourceParser.getEventType() == XmlResourceParser.END_TAG){
                String tagName = xmlResourceParser.getName();
                if (tagName.equals("key")){
                    isInKeyTag = false;
                }
            }
            if (xmlResourceParser.getEventType() == XmlResourceParser.TEXT){
                if (isInKeyTag){
                    String key = xmlResourceParser.getText();
                    keys.add(key);
                }
            }
            xmlResourceParser.next();
        }
        return keys;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```